# Finding the vCPU in a machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, windows-server-2003

How do I know if a Virtual Machine has 0.5 vCPU or 1vCPU? I had been looking at the number of bars in "CPU Usage History" inside performance tab in Task Manager to find that out until recently but the bar stays the same whether it is 0.5vCPU or 1vCPU.

Comment: on what OS and version?

Comment: what virtualization tool?

Comment: OS - Windows 2003 Server; Virtualization Tool - Vmware

Answer (score 1):

I think half a vCPU is still "presented" to the OS as one CPU - you would not expect to see half a bar. I don't think there is a way to find out fractions of the vCPU from within the guest.

This is a kind of "weird" thing to do, because the way to find out how many vCPUs are allocated is through the VMWare Server Console. Are you paying for a guest and worried you are being cheated?